# Why Can't I change value of the variable? Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I made a service that stores a variable I use in two controllers.

```
function CommonVariables() {
    var number = 3;

    return {
        setNumber: function(num) {
            number = num;
        },
        getNumber: function() {
            return number;
        }
    }
};
```

The problem is that I can get this variable like this:

```
this.number = CommonVariables.getNumber();
```

I want it to be changed like this:

```
<input class="numInput" ng-model="Ctrl.number">
```

in Js:

```
function Controller(CommonVariables) {
    this.number = CommonVariables.getNumber();
    CommonVariables.setNumber(this.number);
}
```

But I can't and don't understand why

Comment: You don't have any logic that uses `CommonVariables.setNumber` after `this.number` changes...

Comment: this all code in nit angular.

Answer (score 2):

You need to not only update the variable in the controller, but also send that update back to the service, from which it can be shared to any other part of your application.

=====================================================

edit: working code for me - check your console logs as you run it:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js">    </script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <input class="numInput" ng-model="number" ng-change="changeNumber()">
</div>

</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller("Ctrl", function(CommonVariables, $scope){
        //this will initially set it as the same number as is stored in CommonVariables
        $scope.number = CommonVariables.getNumber();

       //this is the function that will actually send that number back to the service to update it there
       $scope.changeNumber = function() { 
          console.log("Number set:", $scope.number);
          CommonVariables.setNumber($scope.number)
          console.log("Number retrieved after setting:", CommonVariables.getNumber());
      }
     })
     .factory("CommonVariables", function(){
          var number = 3;

          return {
              setNumber: function(num) {
                  number = num;
              },
              getNumber: function() {
                  return number;
             }
        }
 })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to [`$watch`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch) the property `number` in the controller scope.

Inject `$scope` and use

```
function Controller(CommonVariables, $scope) {

    $scope.$watch(angular.bind(this, function () {
        return this.number;
    }), function (newVal) {
        CommonVariables.setNumber(newVal);
    });
...
```

By looking at your code assuming you are using `controller as` syntax